# Two input fields with the same name - on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 input fields with the same name - that is because business logic of the project.

They look like that:

```html
<input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file" id="director_front_passport" />
<input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file" />
```

I need to append image name after input field on change event.But in this way, how to make difference between these 2 inputs?

I thought to try to differ them by `id` attr, but I have `clone` button to add more fields and I don't think this will work on change event.

Updated: My code for on change event is the following:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.app-file' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
 {
  input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
   {
    //my code for displaying image
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I updated my code using `$(this)` to find changed input and my code looks:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.app-file' );

        Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
        {
           input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
            {
              var changed = $(this);
                var label  = changed.next(),
                    labelVal = label.innerHTML,
                    divName = label.next();
               fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();
              divName.html(fileName);
             
             });
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file" id="director_front_passport" />
<input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file" />
```

Comment: why do you need to differentiate between them, will changing either input append an image name?

Comment: Because when user selects file from first input, I need to append image name to it. When user uploads image from second input, to remove image from second.

Comment: why do you have 2 inputs if changing one removes the other? Why not have one input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword within the event handler to identify the element which raised the event. Try this:

```js
$('.app-file').change(function() {
  $(this).after('<div>' + this.files[0].name + '</div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file" id="director_front_passport" />
<input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file" />
```

With your second example it's a little odd to call `forEach` in the manner you are. You can just call `forEach` on the nodeList returned from `querySelectorAll`, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.app-file').forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        // my code for displaying image
    })
}
```

Comment: Would you see my updated question? Is it wrong to use it in this way?

Comment: In this way using foreach like that, I got error: TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).foreach is not a function  and document.querySelectorAll(...).each is not a function

Comment: Firstly, note it's `forEach`, not `foreach`. Although if `querySelectorAll()` fails too it sounds like the browser you're using is outdated and doesn't support newer JS methods. IE or Edge by any chance? I'd use the jQuery version if you need to support those browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know, this way isn't good, but I need to have event listener on change on all inputs. Your answer helped me and I'll update now with my current code. I'm using `$(this)` now.